# Error: command prompt in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, cmd, environment-variables

I have installed and configured MAVEN in a normal CMD, whereas now I want to use this MAVEN in the eclipse cmd. I have configured cmd in Eclipse, but when I execute the command "mvn clean install", the output is **"BUILD FAILURE"** and in the last there is **"'cmd' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file."**
Whereas when i executed **javac** or any other command, the eclipse cmd is able to run.

Comment: What is the result of the `path` command? There seems to be a difference in that between your `normal` CMD and you `eclipse` CMD.

Comment: Here is the output of PATH command
eclipse cmd:"PATH=C:/PROGRA~1/Java/jdk1.7.0_51/bin/../jre/bin/server;C:/PROGRA~1/Java/jdk1.7.0_51/bin/../jre/bin;C:/PROGRA~1/Java/jdk1.7.0_51/bin/../jre/lib/amd64;C:\PROGRA~1\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\bin;C:\PROGRA~1\apache-maven-3.2.1\bin;;C:\Users\manpreet\Desktop\newJUNO\eclipse;"

Normal CMD: "C:\PROGRA`1\Java\jdk....\bin;C:\PROGRA`1\apache-maven-3.2.1\bin"

Comment: Uhm ... Sure that this is the correct output? In your _normal_ CMD you have path entries like `C:\PROGRA'1\...` (note the `'`). Additionally, it seems to be shorter. Maybe you exchanged them?

Comment: yes, this is the correct output according to my system

Comment: Why not upgrade to Eclipse Kepler? - the M2eclipse plugin is installed by default, and you get GUI tools to run maven commands.